# SubSelects for Order and Count

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT Faculty,Department,Season,Student,Score FROM Table
```

I want two new columns like this:

[image: Sample Result Set]

NumberInSeason is order of scores in that faculty, department and season.

TotalInSeason is count of students in that faculty, department and season.

I think i need subselects but can not figure out right now. Any help?

Comment: As you're using sqlServer2012 you have the window functions.  See Row_Number() for enumeration (NumberInSeason). And NTile I think for TotalInSeason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions should do the task:

```
SELECT 
  Faculty, 
  Department, 
  Season, 
  Student, 
  Score, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Faculty, Department, Season ORDER BY Score DESC) AS NumberInSeason, 
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Faculty, Department, Season) AS TotalInSeason 
FROM Table
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

```
SELECT  a.Faculty,a.Department,a.Season,a.Student,Score,count(b.*)  as NumberInSeason , 
SELECT (count(*) FROM table c ON c.Faculty=a.Faculty AND c.Department=a.Department,c.Season=a.Season) AS TotalInSeason 
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN Table b ON a.Faculty=b.Faculty and a.Department=b.Department and a.Season=b.Season and a.score<=b.score
group by a.Faculty,a.Department,a.Season,a.Student,a.Score
```